# written $h(t)$ versus two convex functions

Tags: convex-analysis

given a function $h(t)$ is it possible to written it as a difference of two convex functions $h_1(t)$ and $h_2(t)$ as follow?

$h(t)=h_1(t)+h_2(t)$.

To clarify, every function for example $g(t)$ can be written versus even and odd functions as follow
$g(t)=f_1(t)+f_2(t)$.

where $f_1(t)=(g(t)+g(-t))/2$ and $f_2(t)=(g(t)-g(-t))/2$.

can we write $h(t)$ versus two convex function like in the case of even and odd functions?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Note that convex functions are continuous on the interior of their domain, so a difference of two convex functions also is.